What is the output of the program below with reason
int main()
{
    int N = 2;
    int M = 3;
    int *x[N];
    x=(int(*)[N])malloc(M*sizeof(*x));
    printf("%ld %ld",sizeof(x),sizeof(*x));
}

I want to understand the statement x=(int(*)[N])malloc(M*sizeof(*x));
Output of above program

This line generates a compilation error "error: assignment to expression with array type" : demo.


What is the output of the program

Let's look at a different program first.
int main() {
   int N = 2;
   int *x[ N ];
   printf( "%zu %zu\n", sizeof( x ), sizeof( *x ) );
}

An array (x) is almost always equivalent to a pointer to its first element (&( x[0] )).
These are therefore equivalent:
sizeof( *x )
sizeof( *( &( x[ 0 ] ) ) )
sizeof( *&x[ 0 ] )
sizeof( x[ 0 ] )

sizeof( *x ) is therefore the size of the first element of array x. Since x is an array of pointers to int objects, this is the size of a pointer to an int object.
There are two exceptions to the earlier claim that x is almost always equivalent to a pointer to its first element: sizeof( x ) and similar, and &x.
sizeof( x ) is the size of the array x. The size of an array is the size of its first element multiplied by the number of elements.
So on a system with 8 bit char objects and 64-bit pointers to int objects, the simplified program would output
16 8


But that's not what your program outputs.
Your program isn't valid. It doesn't even compile. So it can't possibly be run, so it can't possibly produce output.
But let's say we fixed the error that prevented it from compiling was fixed. We still couldn't tell you the output of that program. It suffers from many errors that result in its behaviour not being defined, so its output couldn't be predicted.

Based on what I already explained, malloc( M * sizeof( *x ) ) allocates an array of M pointer to int objects.
This is bug #1. Space for N pointers should be allocated.

An object of type int(*)[ N ] is a pointer to an array of N int objects.
This is bug #2. You allocated an array of pointers to int objects, not an array of int objects.

You attempt to assign to an array.
This is bug #3. It is illegal to assign to an array, and it results in a compile-time error.
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:9:6: error: assignment to expression with array type
    9 |     x=(int(*)[N])malloc(M*sizeof(*x));
      |      ^


sizeof evaluates to a value of type size_t. For values of type size_t the %zu format specifier should be used.
Using %ld is bug #4. Using this could result in incorrect values or undefined behaviour.


I want to understand the statement x=(int(*)[N])malloc(M*sizeof(*x));

It's invalid -- an array expression like x cannot be the target of an assignment, so this code won't even compile.  Secondly, whitespace is your friend, don't be afraid to use it:
x = (int (*)[N]) malloc(M * sizeof(*x));

reads a bit easier and makes the mistakes easier to see.
Casting the result of malloc in C (at least after C89) is bad practice, and in this case it's also invalid since the type in the cast doesn't match the type of x -- int *[N] != int (*)[N].
If you're trying to dynamically allocate an NxM array of int, you'd write it as
/**
 * Declare x as a pointer to an M-element
 * array of int.  
 */
int (*x)[M] = NULL;                 

/**
 * Allocate enough memory for N instances of 
 * M-element arrays of int
 */
x = malloc( N * sizeof *x ); 


which for N == 2 and M == 3 gives you something like this:
   +---+      +---+
x: |   | ---> |   | x[0][0]
   +---+      + - +
              |   | x[0][1]
              + - +
              |   | x[0][2]
              +---+
              |   | x[1][0]
              + - +
              |   | x[1][1]
              + - +
              |   | x[1][2]
              +---+

Normally I'd write the allocation as part of the declaration:
int (*x)[M] = malloc( N * sizeof *x );

but either way works.  If I'm declaring the pointer separately I'll initialize it to NULL.
To display various sizes:
printf( "sizeof x == %zu\n", sizeof x );  // prints the size of the *pointer* in bytes
printf( "sizeof *x == %zu\n", sizeof *x); // prints the size of an *M-element array* in bytes 
printf( "sizeof x[0] == %zu\n", sizeof x[0]); // same as above
printf( "N * sizeof x[0] == %zu\n", N * sizeof x[0] ); // prints the size of the entire NxM array in bytes

Use %zu for printing sizeof values, not %ld.  size_t and long int are not guaranteed to have the same size, and size_t is unsigned.
Also, sizeof is an operator (like + and * and ++), not a function; parentheses are only necessary if the operand is a type name like int or double or struct foo.
Since the type of x is int (*)[M], the type of *x is int [M], not int [N][M] -- you will not be able to get the size of the entire allocated 2D array through x.  sizeof *x will yield the same result as sizeof (int) * M.
